# Does detaching a div and appending it increase memory?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if detaching a div on load and appending that same div on a click will increase memory? When you detach a div (filled with images) is the div and image information kept in memory?

For example:

```
<div class="divContain-one">
 <img src="test.png">
</div>

<div class="divContain-two"></div>

 var divContainingImage = $("#divContain-one").detach();

$("button").click(function(){
      $("#divContain-two").append(divContainingImage);
});
```

Comment: The answer probably depends 100% on how the particular browser/JS engine decides to handle it.

Comment: The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time. So if the elements are detached, they should still be in memory and available to be re-attached in the DOM, pending browser compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't increase memory usage significantly. The variable simply contains a reference to same memory that held the DOM element, and any related jQuery data, before it was detached. All that has happened is that the DOM itself no longer has a reference to that memory.

When you append it, you don't increase the memory, either. It simply adds a reference to the same object to the new location in the DOM, it doesn't make a copy.

The information has to be kept in memory -- how else could it know what to add to the DOM when you append?

One caveat: the act of calling `$("#divContainingImage")` creates a jQuery object that wraps around the DOM element, and the variable contains a reference to this object, not just the DOM element. This does increase memory usage, independent of what `.detach()` does.

Comment: I totally agree that memory usage is not significant in this case. But maybe author uses it for hudnreds of elements so he is interested if it will affect memory in such situation.

Comment: @Tamango It's the same memory they used before they were detached. So if he has a million elements in the DOM, and detaches them, the memory doesn't increase due to detaching. But it also doesn't decrease, since there are variables keeping them from being GCed.

Answer (score 0):

According to jquery [documentaion](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) *detach* method **keeps all data associated with the removed element**.

So, **yes**, especially taking the fact that you declared a variable and assigned returned data from *detach* method to it - data is definitely stored in memory. Anyway, keep in mind, that such memory usage is not significant if we are not talking about hundreds or thousands of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to consider if there are event listeners attached to the DOM object.

If you remove an object from the page then the memory can eventually be cleaned once there are no more references to it.

If you remove a  and the  has a click listener then that  can continue to sit in memory indefinitely. Remove the listeners first then remove the DOM object. That way the DOM object can be removed from memory eventually.